# Object required error when using textbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Slide2.TextBox2.Value = Slide2.TextBox1.Value * 0.0225
Slide2.TextBox3.Value = Slide2.TextBox1.Value * 0.1
End Sub
```

Everytime i run the presentation i get an object required error on line 2. I am fairly new to VBA so have no idea how to deal with it

Comment: Maybe there is no `Slide2`, and/or no `TextBox2` and/or no `TextBox1` ? Hit `Debug` and see what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, coding  like this
Val(Slide2.TextBox1.Value)*0.1

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of problems with your code as written.  This will work, assuming, as Tim asks, that there IS a shape named TextBox1 on Slide 2:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("TextBox1")
    .OLEFormat.Object.Text = CStr(CDbl(.OLEFormat.Object.Text) * 0.0225)
End With

End Sub
```

A bit of explanation:

**ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("TextBox1")**

There might be more than one presentation open, so you have to tell VBA which one to look at, in this case the Active presentation, the one you're looking at right now.

**.Slides(2)**

This is the correct syntax to refer to the second slide in the presentation, and from there you need to specify which Shape on the slide you want to work with, so

**.Shapes("TextBox1")**

Since it's an ActiveX shape and not a normal PPT shape, you have to access its properties in a rather odd way:

**.OLEFormat.Object.PropertyName**

In this case, the property name in question is Text ... the text in the textbox.

Then we convert the text in the text box to a number (using CDbl) before doing arithmetic on it, and then convert the result back to a string to stuff into the textbox.

VBA will try to do these string to number, number to string conversions for you automatically, but it's generally better practice to be explicit about what you want rather than going with what VBA ASS-U-MEs you want.